# how to show hidden files using j2me LWUIT api

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I'm making a FileBrowser using LWUIT.

The problem is when I hide a file using `setHidden(true)` the application can never display it
any more using the `listfiles()` so I can't unhide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an omission in LWUIT4IO. I fixed it in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) so it should work as expected there.